# Overlay alpha colour to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm using the following code to overlay 0.5 alpha colour to UIImage. But it seems to be lagging. My image has the size of 2000x1500.

Are there any other ways to overlay alpha colour to UIImage fast?

Thanks.

```
// Tint the image
- (UIImage *)imageWithTint:(UIColor *)tintColor alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    UIImage *image = self;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [[tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put a ```UIView``` on top of the ```UIImageView``` that contains the image?

Comment: @FabioBerger, i need the actual modified image to send to the server.